# Stuck with an old version of MacOS

Tags: macos

I have a 13-inch, Mid 2010 MacBook and I am stuck with the version 10.11.6, I am not able to  make any upgrade. Currently I am not able to download any app from the App Store (only old versions) and I am afraid, soon I will not be able to update some applications (as Unity, VS and GitHub Desktop). Could you help me with any solution? I do not really want to stick with old version on my applications. The replacing of my Mac is not an option

Comment: I have a Mid-2010 iMac and I'm running 10.13.6.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From the looks of the details on [EveryMac.com](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook/specs/macbook-core-2-duo-2.4-white-13-polycarbonate-unibody-mid-2010-specs.html) your Mac will take up to macOS 10.13.x (High Sierra).

Apple's current macOS version is 10.14.x so you are actually in pretty good shape as far as that goes. High Sierra is still getting security updates and most released software will work on the last 2 to 3 macOS versions. Many will work on versions earlier than that.

You should be able to sign into the App Store and download macOS High Sierra. here is a link that will open that up in iTunes, https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/macos-high-sierra/id1246284741?mt=12

Once you have upgraded to High Sierra that will be the last major revision of macOS that is supported on your Mac. Depending on your needs and the apps that you use you *may* need to get yourself a newer Mac that supports macOS Mojave (10.14) and later. But IMHO you probably have a couple of years (at **least**) of life left in your current Mac.

Comment: And to be honest, after 10 years one does expect the laptop to be out of date in many areas; it’s quite impressive that the latest software will still run on it!

Comment: It's not a bad machine as long as you put at least 8GB of RAM into it. Replacing the disk with an SSD helps, but not as much as you would hope. The only problem you tend to run into is that if the OS starts to try and use "Compressed Memory", you'll find the RAM juggling performance of the machine isn't very good; I presume this is a combination of the speed of the CPU but also that it probably lacks some instructions that would speed this kind of operation (e.g. AES256 accelerations). Still, quite usable for day-to-day and light development.

Comment: My experience is that there is nothing better to make a computer feel "snappier" than replacing a spinning drive with an SSD. In some computers it makes the thing feel brand new, in some the difference is subtler but still noticeable. YMMV.